# How to install epylog on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Tags: 20.04

I notice that `epylog` is missing and also is not possible to install using `sudo apt-get install epylog`. Is it replaced by something else? otherwise how to install it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can download packages for it [from 18.04 LTS](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/epylog) and install them manually:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libxml2/python-libxml2_2.9.4+dfsg1-6.1ubuntu1.3_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/e/epylog/epylog_1.0.8-2_all.deb

sudo apt-get install ./python-libxml2_2.9.4+dfsg1-6.1ubuntu1.3_amd64.deb ./epylog_1.0.8-2_all.deb
```

This application is still using Python 2, which is now EOL. It would be really great if you report feature request (or bug) to its developer with request on porting to Python 3. On Ubuntu level I have reported this as [bug 1901389](https://pad.lv/1901389).